# ¿Como ajustar la zona horaria de Mexico en este 2023 - PHP?

Tags: php, php7, timezone

En mi php.ini tengo configurada esta zona horaria **date.timezone = America/Mexico_City** al igual que en el servidor, sin embargo, cuando inserto un registro me toma la hora considerando el horario de Verano pero este 2023 ya no aplica dicho horario, ejemplo: En el registro me toma las 11:00am cuando realmente son las 10:00am.

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

¿Cual pudiera ser la solución para que se respete este cambio que se llevo a cabo en Mexico cancelando el horario de verano?.

Comment: ¿Cuando hablas de *insertar un registro* te refieres a una base de datos? Si es así, ¿qué estás insertando exactamente? ¿Cómo creas el dato a insertar? Pulsa en [edit] y completa la pregunta.

Comment: Los cambios de horario los maneja el sistema operativo, tal vez sólo falte actualizarlo.

Comment: Si no hay actualización de OS disponible aún (sé que Windows ya publicó una, no sé para qué versiones, etc), puede que algo de [esta respuesta](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/693876/130378) te sirva

Comment: *"cuando inserto un registro..."* ¿en dónde?.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Por el momento lo corregí estableciendo otra zona horaria.

```
    date.timezone = "America/Mazatlan"
```

Comment: Revisar [answer]

Comment: Pues está mal. Lo vas a estar corrigiendo cada seis meses?

Answer (score 4):

saludos.
Tuve el mismo problema; lo corregí estableciendo los valores en mi archivo principal de php mediante las siguientes líneas de código:

```
// PHP Version 7.4.26
// Establece zona horaria en la configuración
ini_set('date.timezone',"Etc/GMT-6");
// Horario local
date_default_timezone_set('Etc/GMT-6');
Locale::setDefault('es-MX');
setlocale(LC_TIME, 'es_MX.UTF-8');
```

Espero te sirva de ayuda.
Saludos cordiales.

Comment: Esta me pareció la mejor respuesta pero cuando lo implementé me genera la hora correcta pero del día posterior. :(

Answer (score 1):

#### Detalles generales

Para servidores Ubuntu.

Revisa que tengas la última versión de la base de datos de tiempo. [tzdata](https://www.ubuntuupdates.org/package/core/focal/main/updates/tzdata), sino lo tienes con apt install tzdata debería de bastar.

Ahora esto no es suficiente tzdata actualiza la base de datos del servidor pero no la que utiliza PHP, ahora tienes que ver que versión usas de [timezonedb](https://pecl.php.net/package/timezonedb), para esto ejecuta el siguiente comando en php.

```php
// Si estás debajo de la 2022.7 posiblemente tengas el problema del cambio de horario
echo timezone_version_get();
```

Actualiza el módulo timezonedb, puedes seguir está [guía](https://serverpilot.io/docs/how-to-update-the-php-timezonedb-version/).

Después solo deberías de reiniciar PHP y Apache y los problemas de zona horaria deberían de estar resueltos.

#### En el caso que usen Runcloud está fue nuestra solución

Desde usuario root:

```bash
# Build essential
apt install build-essential autoconf
# Set module name
MODULE_NAME="timezonedb"
# Set download version
MODULE_VERSION="2023.3"
# Download & Extract
cd ~
wget https://pecl.php.net/get/$MODULE_NAME-$MODULE_VERSION.tgz
tar -zxvf $MODULE_NAME-$MODULE_VERSION.tgz
cd $MODULE_NAME-$MODULE_VERSION
# Install
make clean
/RunCloud/Packages/php74rc/bin/phpize --clean
/RunCloud/Packages/php74rc/bin/phpize
./configure --with-php-config=/RunCloud/Packages/php74rc/bin/php-config --with-libdir=lib64 CFLAGS='-O2 -fPIE -fstack-protector-strong -Wformat -Werror=format-security -Wall -pedantic -fsigned-char -fno-strict-aliasing'
make install
echo "extension=$MODULE_NAME.so" > /etc/php74rc/conf.d/$MODULE_NAME.ini
# Restart
systemctl restart php74rc-fpm
```

Answer (score 1):

Yo tenía problemas con timbrado de facturación electrónica por el cambio de horario que tomaba mi postgres; cambié a timezone = 'America/Guatemala' ya que pertenece a UTC "-06:00:00" y el de "America/Mexico_City" sigue estando en "-05:00:00". Me funcionó¡

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
date_default_timezone_set('America/Mexico_City');
// Verificar si el horario de verano está activado
$horarioVerano = date('I'); // Retorna 1 si el horario de verano está activado, 0 si no

// Restar una hora a la hora actual si el horario de verano está activado
if ($horarioVerano) {
  $hoyYahora = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('-1 hour'));
}

// Mostrar la fecha y hora actual con o sin la hora restada
echo 'La fecha y hora actual';
if ($horarioVerano) {
  echo ' (con una hora menos en el horario de verano)';
}
echo ' es: ' . date('H:i:s') . ' del ' . $arrayDia[date('w')] . ', ' . date('d') . ' de ' . $arrayMes[date('n')-1] . ' de ' . date('Y');

?>
```

Comment: Hacer esto para cada valor de fecha que debas procesar puede ser costoso y puede generar conflictos con otras librerías o componentes en el servidor que no estén usando esta lógica. Terminas con valores inesperados en pantalla o en BD y el debug suele ser aburrido y costoso

Comment: La definición de la hora actual a una variable con este código no tiene que ser "costoso" ya que deberías bajo buenas practicas, establecer el momento oportuno previo a cualquier operación a ejecutar. Por ejemplo un constructor solicitando la fecha y hora actual que puede venir de un define('FECHAYHORA',$fechayhora);
Bajo la POO este evento ocurrirá una vez dentro del constructor y bajo la lógica de programación podrías o no continuar obteniendo la fecha y hora actual para cada evento CRUD en cascada que podría ser único o consecuente de cada operación.

Comment: Si, realmente no es la mejor opción ya que implica modificar el código de la aplicación en cada una de las implementaciones de fecha pero en mi caso es un a buena opción ya que solo me afecta en un bloque de código. Al menos mientras logro actualizar a la ultima versión de timezonedb.

Answer (score 1):

Actualiza a la versión más reciente de PHP para que se actualice la base de datos timezonedb. Tendrías que checar si tu aplicación es compatible con la nueva versión de PHP.

Answer (score 0):

Tomando en cuenta lo que decía la regla del horario de verano en México.

> ...Desde entonces, México debía adelantar su reloj una hora cada primer domingo de abril y atrasarlo una hora el último domingo de octubre.

Haciendo uso de la clase [IntlGregorianCalendar](https://www.php.net/manual/es/intlcalendar.indaylighttime.php) podemos identificar si nuestra fecha esta o no en el horario de verano.

```
 $date = new IntlGregorianCalendar(2023, 10 /* Octubre*/, 29); 
        if($date->inDaylightTime()){
            var_dump("horario de verano");
        }else{
            var_dump("no horario de verano");
        }
```

Espero que este pequeño script te ayude.

Comment: Igual puedes desactivar la actualización automatica en tus servers, y si se te escaparon algunos registros yo utilicé esté escript para resolverlo.

Answer (score 0):

En mi caso con mis servidores **macOS** con **xampp** lo que hice fue instalar la extensión de **timezonedb** actualizada.

Primero instalé **mac ports** y después usé la receta que hacia match con mi versión de php:

```
sudo port install php70-timezonedb
```

Al finalizar me genera un archivo timezonedb.so en **/opt/local/lib/php70/extensions/no-debug-non-zts-20151012**

Ese archivo lo moví a la carpeta de extensiones de php de mi instalación de xampp y al finalizar solo edité el archivo php.ini para agregar la extensión:

**extension="timezonedb.so"**

Reiniciamos apache y listo!

Answer (score 0):

Si usas MAMP, solo ve a MAMP > bin > php > php[8.1.x o la versión de tu interés] > conf > php.ini. Haz los cambios, por ejemplo: date.timezone = "America/Lima". Luego, REINICIA todo el equipo. Debes ver los cambios después de reiniciar.